# Fails to clone repo on Windows with GitKraken

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, gitkraken

Im wondering, what im doing wrong, when I use GitKraken on windows, and try to pull any of my repos from Github, that has LFS.
I tried that actually on 4 windows machines around me, and every time in breaking my head, and Im just using gitbash instead.

Example of usage on completely fresh PC.
Download gitkraken,
create SSH, add that to my github account, ensure it is set everywhere in gitkraken, this just recently created SSH.
Then every time when I try to pull LFS content I receive permission denied...
And this is the same on 4 PCs around me.
What works - is to open git bash, and do following with generated ssh:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K C:/Users/root/Documents/gitkraken_rsa
```

P.S. On mac all works smoothly.
What Im doing wrong? Just tired to spend time on that...

Comment: "On mac all works smoothly." You mean on mac it works with GitKraken, the same settings, the same key and the same repository? Also, where are the ssh key files located? Your home directory?

Comment: have you ran `git install lfs` on this machine yet?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fixed that by clicking button Use your default key for github...